# Merge array while transforming into a different form in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of the below format

```
cars = [
{id: 1, make: 'audi', year: '2010', someProperty: true},
{id: 2, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false},
{id: 3, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
{id: 4, make: 'vw', year: '2010', someProperty: true},
{id: 5, make: 'vw', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
{id: 6, make: 'audi', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
{id: 7, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: false},
{id: 8, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false},
{id: 9, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: true}
]
```

and transforming it into the below format,

```
requiredFormat = [
  { 
    somePropertyTrue: [
      {id: 1, make: 'audi', year: '2010', someProperty: true},
      {id: 4, make: 'vw', year: '2010', someProperty: true},
      {id: 9, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: true} 
    ],
    somePropertyFalse: [
      {id: 7, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: false}
    ],
    year: '2010'
  }, 
  {
    somePropertyTrue: [
      {id: 3, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
      {id: 5, make: 'vw', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
      {id: 6, make: 'audi', year: '2011', someProperty: true}
    ],
    somePropertyFalse: [
      {id: 2, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false},
      {id: 8, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false}
    ],
    year: '2011'
  }
]
```

I am using the transform function as below,

```
function transform(cars) {
    return [...cars.reduce ( (acc, car) => {
        const yearGrp = acc.get(car.year) || { 
            somePropertyTrue: [], 
            somePropertyFalse: [],
            year: car.year
        };
        yearGrp['someProperty' + (car.someProperty ? 'True' : 'False')].push(car);
        return acc.set(car.year, yearGrp);
    }, new Map).values()];
}
```

I am reading the first array using readline and pausing every 2000 items, I am trying to extend the above function to accept the previously transformed array so that all the transformed items are merged to one array, I tried the below but I know it is not the way to approach this.

```
let transform = function transform(cars) {
    return [...cars.reduce((acc, arr) => {
        if (!first) {
            parsedArray.reduce((a) => {
                const yearGrp = a.get(arr.year) ||
                    acc.get(arr.year) || {
                        somePropertyTrue: [], 
                        somePropertyFalse: [],
                        year: arr.year
                    };
                yearGrp['someProperty' + (car.someProperty ? 'True' : 'False')].push(arr);
                return a.set(arr.year, yearGrp);
            });
        } else {
            const yearGrp = acc.get(arr.year) || {
                somePropertyTrue: [], 
                somePropertyFalse: [],
                year: arr.year
            };
            yearGrp['someProperty' + (car.someProperty ? 'True' : 'False')].push(arr);
            return acc.set(arr.year, yearGrp);
        }
    }, new Map())];
};
```

here, parsedArray is something I tried to populate the first time and trying to use that every other time, 'first' is a flag

Comment: it's better to keep the map/`acc` for further inserting of data. you might take a snapshot out of it if you need the converted data. nice morphing from cars to crime ;-)

Comment: forgot about the update, will edit that :) thanks

Comment: how do i take a snapshot of acc, even if i take it, then how do i reuse the same the second time?

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` solution:

```js
var cars = [
    {id: 1, make: 'audi', year: '2010', someProperty: true}, {id: 2, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false},
    {id: 3, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: true}, {id: 4, make: 'vw', year: '2010', someProperty: true},
    {id: 5, make: 'vw', year: '2011', someProperty: true}, {id: 6, make: 'audi', year: '2011', someProperty: true},
    {id: 7, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: false}, {id: 8, make: 'bmw', year: '2011', someProperty: false},
    {id: 9, make: 'bmw', year: '2010', someProperty: true}
],
requiredFormatData = [];
// grouping by 'year'
groups = cars.reduce(function(r, o){ 
    var k = 'someProperty' + ((o.someProperty)? 'True':'False');
    if (r[o.year]){ 
     (r[o.year][k]) && r[o.year][k].push(o) || (r[o.year][k] = [o]);
    } else {
     r[o.year] = {year: o.year};
     r[o.year][k] = [o];
        requiredFormatData.push(r[o.year]);
    }
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(requiredFormatData);
```

Comment: The problem here is if requiredFormatData already has a year 2010 and second time when groups is called, it will not check that and adds a duplicate 2010 year to requiredFormatData, I am trying to merge this together

Comment: @Sriram, I don't see a test case where my approach would *adds a duplicate 2010* as you said. Your new issue is unclear and the solution gives expected output

Comment: This is not a new issue i am talking about, if you split the above array into two and then execute the groups function twice, you can see that.. This is what i have mentioned in the question. I want this to be done every 2000 items once.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep the map/`acc` for further inserting of data. You might take a snapshot out of it if you need the converted data.

You could use a closure over the map and return the function, like

```js
var transform = (m => array => (array.forEach(a => m.set(...a)), [...m]))(new Map);

console.log(transform([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]));
console.log(transform([['c', 3], ['d', 4]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```